# Unit test xml generator using XSD

Tags: c++, xml, googletest

I'm developing an app that generates XML. What's the best approach to unit test generation code?

I use C++, gtest, gmock.

I suppose one of them is to generate XML in test code and check if it conforms XSD schema. Is there libraries I can use to check XSD?

Another way, i think, is to generate xml using DOM. This way i can unit test DOM instead of XML code. But this approach requires more additional classes to represent DOM.

So what's best approach and tools for this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you actually want to test. If you just want to test the generation make sure you simplify the interface so it accepts the inputs that it needs and spits out the XML as a string. It's then very simple to test with fixed input and verify the results against hardcoded expected XML.